# Как сгруппировать значения до нулевых значений в поле?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица card_info:

```
Клиент Дата Баланс
1   01.03.2010 150
1   02.03.2010 100
1   03.03.2010 200
1   04.03.2010 0
1   05.03.2010 50
1   06.03.2010 0
2   16.03.2010 1000
2   17.03.2010 0
```

Для каждого клиента нужно вывести все периоды, где баланс отличен от нуля и средний баланс

Должна получиться такая табличка:

```
Клиент Дата1 дата2 Баланс
1   01.03.2010 03.03.2010 150
1   05.03.2010 05.03.2010 50
2   16.03.2010 16.03.2010 1000
```

Не понимаю как остановиться в группировке на 0, знаю про функцию lead для partition by которая показывает следующий элемент, но как она поможет распознать до куда группировать пока непонятно. Буду рад любой подсказке)

Comment: ругается на not

Comment: Там по периоду ещё группировка

Comment: То что до 0 в один период обьединить

Comment: А если написать where balance 0 это не тоже самое?

Comment: *А если написать where balance 0 это не тоже самое?* Если написать так, то это syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Диалект не указан - даю решение для MySQL.

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, SUM(NOT Balance) OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY `Date`) grp
              FROM test )
SELECT Client,
       MIN(`Date`) Date1,
       MAX(`Date`) Date2,
       AVG(Balance) Balance
FROM cte 
WHERE Balance
GROUP BY Client, grp
ORDER BY Client, grp;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=64b5f67ef7cf5baee90fce34d97c37ac